# Type 'FormGroup | null' is not assignable to type 'FormGroup'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'FormGroup'. Angular 11

Tags: html, angular, api, angular-reactive-forms

I am new to Angular, I use version 11.
And I have a problem with the formGroup attribute in my html file.

Error :

'FormGroup | null' is not assignable to type 'FormGroup'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'FormGroup'.

2     <form [formGroup]="produitFormGroup">

My html code.

```
 <form [formGroup]="produitFormGroup">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Nom</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Prix</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="price">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Quantite</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="quantity">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Selected</label>
        <input type="checkbox" formControlName="selected">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Available</label>
        <input type="checkbox" formControlName="available">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success">Enregistrer</button>
</form>
```

And my ts file code:

```
produitFormGroup: FormGroup | null= null;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit(): void {

   this.produitFormGroup = this.fb.group({
   name:["", Validators.required],
   price:[0, Validators.required],
   quantity:[0, Validators.required],
   selected:[true, Validators.required],
   available:[true, Validators.required]

 });

}
```

Comment: You can just remove the `null` type declaration and the problem should go away.  `produitFormGroup: FormGroup | null= null;` would become `produitFormGroup: FormGroup;`, so you understand why the formGroup directive only takes an argument of type FormGroup, you have declared yours as type FormGroup "or" null, which is why you are seeing that error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I removed it but the problem persists ....

Comment: And when I declare produitFormGroup: FormGroup; I have this error : Property 'produitFormGroup' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Comment: Could you try to initialize the form in the constructor?. And the declaration, just leave: produitFormGroup: FormGroup;

Answer (score 30):

You need to add ! operator after produitFormGroup like this:

```
produitFormGroup!: FormGroup;
```

It is a way to tell the compiler explicitly that an expression has value other than **null** or **undefined**

Comment: Thanks, it works! Does this solution have any drawbacks?

Answer (score 9):

Actually at `produitFormGroup: FormGroup | null= null;` Statement you are trying to assign *null value* to the *FormGroup* explicitly but the problem is TypeScript's type checker doesn't allow these kind of assignment.

### Solution 1 :(By Changing null checking flags)

- change `produitFormGroup: FormGroup | null= null;` to `produitFormGroup: FormGroup;`.
- change `"strict": true,` to `"strict": false,` on tsconfig.json
- here,the TS compilers type checker will permanently ignore the  null and undefined value checking for whole project.

### Solution 2 (By using ! operator) [Recomended]

- change `produitFormGroup: FormGroup | null= null;` to `produitFormGroup!: FormGroup;`.
- Here, The *non-null assertion operator(!)* will take care of *null and undefined* values

[Checkout this link to find some other ways to fix or know about this issue.](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-type-null-is-not-assignable-to-type-string)

Comment: I just want to provide a warning about the `!` operator, and that your suggestion "will take care of null and undefined values". What you're saying is technically incorrect and misleading. The non-null assertion operator is essentially foregoing null/undefined type checking on this property and should be done with care. The `!` operator is "turning off" a great typescript feature.

I wouldn't say `!` is always recommended. Instead provide a valid default value when you declare the property.

Answer (score 4):

If initializing the **FormGroup** isn't an option (if it is an input property on a child component for example) using an ngIf statement will pass the strict template checking:

```html
  <form *ngIf="produitFormGroup" [formGroup]="produitFormGroup">
    ...
  </form>
```

Answer (score 3):

## Problem Analysis

Basically the problem is that in the line `<form [formGroup]="produitFormGroup">` you are expected to pass a `FormGroup` but you are passing `FormGroup | null` So basically when the value of `produitFormGroup` is null, your code will fail, luckily typescript has captured this error for you

## Solution

Whenever I need to initialize my Forms I simply initialize them when declaring the property, something like below

```typescript
produitFormGroup = this.fb.group({
   name:["", Validators.required],
   price:[0, Validators.required],
   quantity:[0, Validators.required],
   selected:[true, Validators.required],
   available:[true, Validators.required]
 });;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit(): void {

}
```

### What About the type ?

I have intentionally omitted typing. `this.fb.group({ ... })` returns a `FormGroup` so by [Inferance](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) `produitFormGroup` is assigned type `FormGroup`